# FB Async Feed failing on Authentication

Tags: facebook, api, oauth

The code below has been used for several month successfully. But recently, it stopped working. The objective is to pull the latest feed from a facebook page. The response is now "An access token is required to request this resource." But reading the JS SDK docs never suggest anything more than an app ID for this method. What is the real error here?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() { 
    FB.init({appId: '<?php echo $this->appId; ?>', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
    FB.api('/<?php echo $this->appId; ?>/feed', {'limit': <?php echo (int)$this->feedLimit; ?>}, function(response) {
        if(response.data[0]) {
            jQuery('.facebook .comment p a').append(response.data[0].message);
        }
    });
};
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); 
    e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, that should work (if your app ID is indeed correct): did the app ID somehow change to a user ID in the recent past?

EDIT: ah, must be a recent change in the platform. I'm guessing accessing app feeds now need a token. See http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/510/ for details.